# Помогите с css пожалуйста

Tags: css

Нужен черный фон что бы поверх можно было написать текст,спасибо большое заранее!
Не особо понимаю JS и Css но срочно нужен такой простенький код

Comment: А с чем у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Прочитайте как изменить цвет [фона](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) и [текста](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value)

Comment: `<body style="color: white; background-color:black">text</body>`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">Этот текст можно редактировать!</div>
```